# How do I compile standalone files in TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio, standalone

I get some unexpected behavior when I try to "Build & View" or "Compile" the `standalone` file `mysubfile.tex` in TeXstudio.

The following results in **expected** behavior:

1. Open fresh session of TeXstudio
2. Open **only** `mysubfile.tex` (which resides in a folder containing only this file and `mymainfile.tex`)
3. Build & View (or Compile)
4. Message output produced:

[image]

5. and `mysubfile.pdf` produced, which is just the cropped text "Some subfile text".

[image]

as expected.

But the following results in **unexpected** behavior:

If I then open `mymainfile.tex` in TeXstudio, re-select the `mysubfile.tex` window, and Build & View, then:

[image]

`mymainfile.pdf`:

[image]

I get the **same** output even if I then close `mymainfile.tex` in TeXstudio, get rid of all the produced files in my project folder (so that only `mymainfile.tex` and `mysubfile.tex` remain), and Build & View `mysubfile.tex`. **What!?** Somehow TeXStudio is aware that this is not a fresh session.

I looked to the TeXstudio command configurations

[image]

**Q1:** How does TeXstudio decide which filename (`mymainfile` or `mysubfile`) is passed to pdflatex through `%`

**Q2:** How can I fix this so that when I Build & View with the `mysubfile.tex` window selected, `mysubfile` is passed to pdflatex rather than `mymainfile`?

**mymainfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
  My main file text.
  \input{mysubfile.tex}
\end{document}
```

**mysubfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Some subfile text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an option which tells it not to automatically detect a 'master' file, for example? The terminology might differ - that's what Kile calls it.

Comment: @cfr: Awesome. Once I searched using the 'master' terminology you mentioned I found [this comment on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/476/#6f8e). So all I need to do: Select `subfile.tex` > ALT + O > Select "Define Current Document as 'Master Document'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `subfile.tex` > ALT + O + M > Build & View.

Answer (score 5):

As of version 2.8.10, accelerator keys for setting the explicit root document do no longer work.

However, TeXStudio supports a magic comment (at the beginning of the document)

```
% !TeX root = FILENAME.tex
```

that allows setting file that is used when *Options > Root Document > Detect automatically* is enabled.

So basically, the root-document resolution order is

1. The explicitly set file, as set by *Options > Root Document > Set Current Document As Explicit Root*
2. The file indicated by the `% !TeX root` magic comment.
3. The root file detected from analyzing currently opened files.